# Iterating over an equation given an array

Tags: python, numpy, loops

So I want to compute the outputs of a formula given an array of inputs
For example

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
variables = np.array([2,5])

def Y(X,variables):
    return = X*(variables[0]-variables[1])
```

and then the outputs in an array Y

I think a for loop is the way but I couldn't figure out how.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def Y(X, variables):
    return X*(variables[0]-variables[1])

X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
variables = np.array([2,5])

Y = Y(X, variables)
print(Y)
```

Although, I would not suggest you to use the same name for function and variable, so you can change it yourself.